# ...a) Show that any metric $d$ on $X$ satisfies the above two properties. b) Show that if $d$ satisfies both the first and second properties...

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces, alternative-proof

Let $X$ be a set. Consider the following properties referring to a function
$d : X \times X \to \mathbb R$:

$d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$;

$d(x, z) \le d(z, y) + d(y, x)\;$ whatever $\;x, y, z \in X$.

a) Show that any metric $d$ on $X$ satisfies the above two properties.

b) Show that if $d$ satisfies both the first and second properties, then
$d$ is a metric over $X$.

c) Let $X = \mathbb R$. Show that:

(i). $d(x, y) = x − y$ satisfies the first property, but not the second;

(ii).$d(x, y) = |x − y| + 1$ satisfies the second property, but not the first.

---

If it is metric then:

$d(x, x) = 0$ whatever $x \in X$;

$d(x, y) = d(y, x)$ whatever that looks like $x, y \in X$;

$d(x, z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)$ whatever that looks like $x, y, z \in X$.

a)(=>) $d(x, y) = d(y, x) = 0 = d(x,x) = d(y,y) \to x = y$
(<=) $x = y \to d(y,y) = d(x,x) = 0 = d(y, x) = d(x,y)$

$d(x, z) \le d(z, y) + d(y, x) \to d(x, z) \le d(y, z) + d(x, y) \to d(x , z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)$

b) is not the same thing as item a)?

c) $d(x, y) = x − y = 0 = d(y,x) = y-x \to x = y $

(i).$d(x, z) \le d(z, y) + d(y, x) \to x-z \le z-y + y-x \to x-z \le z-x$

Or that it is true only for $x = z$.

(ii).$d(x, y) = d(y, x) = |x − y| + 1 = 0 $ else if $x=y \to |x − x| +1 \ne $0

$d(x, z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z) \to |x − z| + 1\le |x − y| + 1 + |y − z| + 1 \to |x − z| \le |x − y| + |y − z| + 1$

Stuck here,

the other attempts are acceptable?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: quaisquer will not be understood by people who do not know Portuguese.

Comment: For c). (ii) Prove $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$. If $ab\geq 0$ equality holds. Then it's easy to show $|a+b|+1<|a|+1+|b|+1$.

Comment: For your answer to c) (i) $x-z\leq z-x$ is true for all $x, z\in \mathbb R$ with $x\leq z$.